# How do I get a function response based on the parameters passed?

Tags: typescript

I would like to access the types of copied array elements, but I don't know how :C

```js
let inputArray = [
    {
        test: 1,
    },
    {
        test: 2,
    },
];

function clone(array: any[]): any[] {
    return Array.from(inputArray);
}

let outputArray = clone(inputArray);
outputArray[0].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this signature for `clone` to let TS infer the type of passed array and consequently the type of return value:

```
clone<T extends any[]>(array: T)
```

After that, you'll be able to use property access correctly.